# Solr – Configure SeachHandler's SeachComponent with minimum match = 100% and still ignore stop words from search query

Tags: solr, stop-words

We have our index analyzer configured with solr.StopFilterFactory. So stopwords are not indexed.

We also have our query analyzer configured with solr.StopFilterFactory as we wanted stopwords to be ignored from search query terms

```
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
  ... ...
```

In solrconfig.xml, Select SearchHandler is configured to use SearchComponent parameter minimum match = 100 %

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>           
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="mm">100%</str>
        <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    ... ...
```

This results in some of our multi word search queries to return no result e.g "rite in the rain". Due to settings above "in" and "the" are not indexed but minimum match is making them mandatory even though query analyzer is configured to remove stopwords.

Is there any setting that will allow us to achieve this ?

Comment: check if the mm.autorelax param can help https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser

Comment: as mentioned below mm.autorelax is available for solr >= 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation you must take account of the different `fieldTypes` involved in the query, distinguishing between these 2 categories : `solr.TextField` types defined with the same stop filter, and other fields. The different types involved depends on the query fields requested via the `qf` parameter.

If the query contains stopwords and the 2 categories of fields are mixed in `qf` you will get the issue because there will always remain a required clause attempting to match a stopword on a "non-stop-filtered" field (e.g. numeric field or text field without stop filter), unless you set a lower `mm`.

[`mm.autoRelax`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Themm.autoRelaxParameter) param for edismax parser is intended to handle this wrong behavior and is available since Solr 6.0 ([SOLR-3085](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3085)) :

> If true, the number of clauses required (minimum should match) will
>   automatically be relaxed if a clause is removed (by e.g. stopwords
>   filter) from some but not all qf fields. Use this parameter as a
>   workaround if you experience that queries return zero hits due to
>   uneven stopword removal between the qf fields.

If you can't use `mm.autoRelax` and as long as you need `mm=100%`, you will have to set `qf` with only text fields that use the *same* stop filter (same params and dictionary) to guarantee a consistent behavior when the query contains stopwords.

Comment: Different field types in `qf` was our problem. One field was string (no stop filter) and another was `text_en_splitting_tight` ( had stopfilter but missing `enablePositionIncrements=true` ) . Making fieldtype of all fields to a type with stopfilter with same settings solved the issue.